# padding/margin issue with collapsed margins

Tags: html, css

I want to raise quotation marks higher, but whenever i add padding or margin bottom nothing happens, it seems that parent does not contain the children. I have tried border solid, inline block, everything i know to use when margins collapse but nothing worked

```css
blockquote {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 170px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #B08177;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 209px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 5px;
}

.fa-quote-left {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<blockquote>

  <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Text!
  <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</blockquote>
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use `.fa-quote-left { position: relative; top: -20px; }` ?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But why doesn't padding work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
blockquote {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-top: 170px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #B08177;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 0;
  border: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 209px;
}

.fa {
  font-size: 5px;
}

.fa-quote-left {
  bottom:12px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<blockquote>

  <i class="fa fa-quote-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> My Text!
  <i class="fa fa-quote-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</blockquote>
```

Comment: The quote is actually in a `:before` pseudo element created on the `i`, any padding applied to the `inline` `i` element only affects that, and not any pseudo elements on it.